# Python - how to fix this line typeerror: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: bash, awk

From command line its working but when i include in the Python getting this

Terminal:

```
$ amixer -c2 | grep "Simple mixer control 'Mic',0" -A 5 | grep "Mono: " | sed -e 's/Capture /\n/g' | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/%]//g' | sed -e 's/\[//g'
88
```

Python:

```
tmp = "2"
a = """amixer -c%s | grep "Simple mixer control 'Mic',0" -A 5 | grep "Mono: " | sed -e 's/Capture /\n/g' | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/%]//g' | sed -e 's/\[//g'""" % tmp
print "Reply " + a
a = os.popen(a).read()
print a
```

Error:

```
Running: /var/tmp/p/test.py (Sun Dec  8 20:58:07 2013)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/tmp/p/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    a = """amixer -c%s | grep "Simple mixer control 'Mic',0" -A 5 | grep "Mono: " | sed -e 's/Capture /\n/g' | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/%]//g' | sed -e 's/\[//g'""" % tmp
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string


Execution Successful!
```

Comment: try: a=r('amixer -c2 | grep "Simple mixer control 'Mic',0" -A 5 | grep "Mono: " | sed -e 's/Capture /\n/g' | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/%]//g' | sed -e 's/\[//g'
88')  . Not really sure but raw string should do the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see that thing in one of the `sed`:

```
... | sed -e 's/%]//g' | ...
```

Change that bit to this:

```
... | sed -e 's/%%]//g' | ...
```

This is how you escape a `%` in strings in `python`.

Comment: After having pass from %%, then i now get this: `Reply amixer -c2 | grep "Simple mixer control 'Mic',0" -A 5 | grep "Mono: " | sed -e 's/Capture /
/g' | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/%]//g' | sed -e 's/\[//g'

sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated `s' command

grep: write error: Broken pipe`